# List of distinct XML element names using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, tags, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse an XML document. Is there a straight-forward way to get a list of distinct element names that are used in the document?

For example, if this is the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to> Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I would like to get:
note, to, from, heading, body

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and get the [`.name`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name) for every tag found:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to> Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
print [tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()]
```

Prints:

```
['note', 'to', 'from', 'heading', 'body']
```

Note that for this to work, you need to have `lxml` module installed, since, according to the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

> Right now, the only supported XML parser is lxml. If you don’t have
>   lxml installed, asking for an XML parser won’t give you one, and
>   asking for “lxml” won’t work either.

---

And, to follow this up, then why don't use a special XML parser directly?

Example, using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de):

```
from lxml import etree

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to> Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(data)
print [item.tag for item in tree.xpath('//*')]
```

Prints:

```
['note', 'to', 'from', 'heading', 'body']
```

---

To follow this, why use a third-party for such a simple task?

Example, using [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from standard library:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, ElementTree

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to> Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
"""

tree = ElementTree(fromstring(data))
print [item.tag for item in tree.getiterator()]
```

Prints:

```
['note', 'to', 'from', 'heading', 'body']
```